# Satellizer Angularjs Login with G+ and facebook getting weired response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-oauth, facebook-oauth, satellizer

I am implementing login with fb and google using satellizer.
In my controller i have written the code .:

```
 $scope.authenticate = function(provider) {
        $auth.authenticate(provider).then(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp)
        });
    };
```

in the response i get the following date.
**Expecting a token named "token**

**Object {data: "", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
config: Object
data: "Header"
headers: (name)
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object**

I dont think the response is right OR what should be the next step.